# What's the best way to create a custom sharing method on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

A streaming app that I'm using on iOS has a share button that allows me to hook into the sharing app extension. I'd like to be able to send the URL string that it has to a custom API on my server.

1. Would I need to create an entire app just to have that custom sharing method, or is there another way?
2. If that's the only way, how can I get that app on my phone without going through the store?
3. It seems like when I create, build and install apps through Xcode, Apple intentionally breaks the app after a short while?

Comment: Question 1. Yes

Comment: Question 2. Installing it locally should be enough.

Comment: Question 3. This is very evasive: what do you mean? Can you share the error you get?

Comment: Thanks for responding! Fair enough on point 3. Anytime I install an app directly from Xcode (I've only ever done it with Unity3D for work, which exports an Xcode project that I'm able to build and install.) But any build that I create and put on the Iphone breaks after a while. Unfortunately, I don't remember if there was an error, it's been a while since I've seen the problem. Based on your answer to question number two though, it sounds like that's not by design and a misunderstanding on my part. Thank you again for answering my questions!